# XML Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Where Can I find good tutorial about XMl serialization to the object?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a basic tutorial on [Microsoft's support pages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) and their code example is only a few lines long:

```
using System;

public class clsPerson
{
  public  string FirstName;
  public  string MI;
  public  string LastName;
}

class class1
{ 
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      clsPerson p=new clsPerson();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Basically you don't have to anything other than call the built in functions that do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 7):

Its really pretty simple, there are only three main steps.

1. You need to mark your classes with the `[Serializable]` attribute.
2. Write Serialization code
3. Write Deserialization code

Serialization:

```
var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));
var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\YourFile.xml"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
x.Serialize(fs, yourInstance);
fs.Close();
```

Deserialization:

```
var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));
var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\YourFile.xml"), FileMode.Open);
var fromFile = x.Deserialize(fs) as YourClass;
fs.Close();
```

Comment: For XML serialization, the [Serializable] attribute is not necessary. The [Serializable] attribute is needed for binary serialization.

Comment: @Xenan +1 for mentioning that `[Serializable]` is superfluous for XML Serialization

Answer (score 2):

[XML Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

[How to serialize an object to XML by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a decent article about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx

And this one's a bit more straightforward: http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ms950721.aspx)

Also look into Xml Schema and generating classes automatically with [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) the sooner you get used to this the better, it can save you a lot of effort working with XML. Also looking at the generated c# files gives you some clues on how to use attributes to manipulate the way classes are serilized by the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find many tutorials about serialization data using .Net on the Web. However, let me remind some  points:

1. Types of serialization:

   a. XML Serialization :  Please have a look at http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

   b. Binary Serialization: Please refer to http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file
2. Also please be aware of the security aspects when you work (reading and writing data) with  files. There is a good tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We use `Serialization` to write the data in Binary Format and IN XML format.
for binary format we use `BibnaryFormatSerialization` and for XML format we use `SoapFormatSerialization`.