# LINQ XML Read Elements to variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read this xml file into C# into a variable or a set of variable.

```
<ROWSET>
  <ROW num="1">
     <USER_ID></USER_ID>
     <FIRST_NAME>Timothy</FIRST_NAME>
     <MIDDLE_NAME></MIDDLE_NAME>
     <LAST_NAME>Scott</LAST_NAME>
     <EMPLOYEE_NO>99</EMPLOYEE_NO>
     <HOME_PHONE></HOME_PHONE>
     <EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>T</EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>
     <HIRE_DATE>01/01/01</HIRE_DATE>
     <DEPARTMENT>Engineering</DEPARTMENT>
     <POSITION>Controls Engineer</POSITION>
     <SHIFT>N</SHIFT>
     <REPORTS_TO>Everhart,Robert</REPORTS_TO>
     <PAY_TYPE>H</PAY_TYPE>
     <EMPLOYEE_TYPE>R</EMPLOYEE_TYPE>
     <TERMINATION_DATE>value</TERMINATION_DATE>
     <PCN_CODE>stuff-RV</PCN_CODE>

  </ROW>
  <ROW num="2">
     <USER_ID>RV100707</USER_ID>
     <FIRST_NAME>Jan</FIRST_NAME>
     <MIDDLE_NAME>G</MIDDLE_NAME>
     <LAST_NAME>Pot</LAST_NAME>
     <EMPLOYEE_NO>80</EMPLOYEE_NO>
     <HOME_PHONE></HOME_PHONE>
     <EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>A</EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>
     <HIRE_DATE>01/01/01</HIRE_DATE>
     <DEPARTMENT>Shipping</DEPARTMENT>
     <POSITION>Shipping Coordinator</POSITION>
     <SHIFT>2</SHIFT>
     <REPORTS_TO>Hajkova,Karin</REPORTS_TO>
     <PAY_TYPE>H</PAY_TYPE>
     <EMPLOYEE_TYPE>R</EMPLOYEE_TYPE>
     <TERMINATION_DATE></TERMINATION_DATE>
     <PCN_CODE>stuff-RV</PCN_CODE>
```

I Have looked at a few of the examples but none of the preserved the elements. I also Would like to loop through till the end of the file having only one ROW per run through there. So that another function can grab those values and send them to where they need to go.

For example:
          ROW elements: 
 Loop till end of xml doc

```
<USER_ID></USER_ID>
 <FIRST_NAME>Timothy</FIRST_NAME>
 <MIDDLE_NAME></MIDDLE_NAME>
 <LAST_NAME>McCreary</LAST_NAME>
 <EMPLOYEE_NO>1048</EMPLOYEE_NO>
 <HOME_PHONE></HOME_PHONE>
 <EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>T</EMPLOYEE_STATUS_>
 <HIRE_DATE>05/17/2010</HIRE_DATE>
 <DEPARTMENT>Engineering</DEPARTMENT>
 <POSITION>Controls Engineer</POSITION>
 <SHIFT>N</SHIFT>
 <REPORTS_TO>Everhart,Robert</REPORTS_TO>
 <PAY_TYPE>H</PAY_TYPE>
 <EMPLOYEE_TYPE>R</EMPLOYEE_TYPE>
 <TERMINATION_DATE>07/01/2010</TERMINATION_DATE>
 <PCN_CODE></PCN_CODE>
```

Upload to HTTP //I have this part figured out.

ROW = ROW 2 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of dealing with XML using .NET and C#.

Some i know of:

- LINQ to XML (like [Tyress answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748993/1469035))
- XML Serialization (See : [XML Serialization in C# -- Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195867/1469035))
- And the way i show here (XPath):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(@"PathToYourFile\file.xml"));
XmlNode rowset = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ROWSET"); // <-- This variable provides access to the root XML node

// The .Cast<> is needed because LINQ works only generic Collections.
// The .ToList() executes the LINQ query and store the result in a List<> (usually faster than using the IEnumerable<> directly but also higher memory usage)
List<XmlNode> rows = rowset.SelectNodes("ROW").Cast<XmlNode>().ToList(); 

foreach (XmlNode row in rows)
{
    // access attibutes of row with:
    string numValue = row.Attributes["num"].InnerText;

    // access sub-elements of row with:
    string employeeNo = row.SelectSingleNode("EMPLOYEE_NO").InnerText;

    // You can even go deeper through an XML hierarchy with:
    // row.SelectSingleNode("SomeXMLNode/SubNode/NodeOfSubNode").InnerText;
}

// Select the 2nd row
XmlNode secondRow = rows.Single(r => r.Attributes["num"].InnerText == "2");
```

Comment: Just FYI @MC, your answer *is* the XPath solution :P as SelectNode and SelectSingleNode's parameters expect XPath strings.

Comment: @Tyress Ok, i mixed them up. Whats your method (using `XElement`) called then?

Comment: XElement is under LINQ to XML, so it would probably be the "LINQ" method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use XDocument (`using System.Xml.Linq;`) to parse the document. Usage is something like this:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("yourfilename.xml"));
    XElement rowset = doc.Element("ROWSET"); // get the ROWSET element
    XElement row1 = rowset.Elements("ROW").First(); // get the first child ROW of ROWSET
    //get the ROW child of ROWSET having attribute num == 2
    XElement row2 = rowset.Elements().Single(row => row.Attribute("num").Value == "2");
```

When you say you only want one row per one run through, I'm assuming you want to focus on a single row each iteration (right?). You can use a foreach on ROWSET's child ROW elements

```
    foreach (XElement row in rowset.Elements())
    {
        string firstname = row.Element("FIRST_NAME").Value;
        // etc
    }
```